# Rails 3 serialized model field form_for and field_for not generating correct name

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, haml

I have this model:

```
class CompanyCrawler < ActiveRecord::Base
  .... 
  serialize :entry_pages, Array

  def entry_page_objects
    entry_pages.map { |url| EntryPage.new(url) }
  end

  def entry_page_objects_attributes=(attributes)
    # ...
  end
  ....
end
```

This form to render the model:

```
.....
%p
  %p
    = crawler_form.label 'Entry pages'
  = crawler_form.text_area :entry_pages_text, size: '80x6'
  %ul.entry-pages
    = crawler_form.fields_for :entry_page_objects do |entry_page_field|
      %li=entry_page_field.text_field :url, size: 80
    %a{href: '#', class: 'add-button'} Add Entry Page
```

The problem I have is that the form renders the `entry_page_object` input names incorrectly(e.g. `company_crawler[entry_page_objects_attributes][0][url]` instead of `company_crawler[entry_page_objects][0][url]`). I am really not sure what to do, I have read the documentation and the example says that just by defining `attr_attributes=(attributes)` and `persisted?` I will be able to use `fields_for` for collections just if they were associations defined with `accept_nested_fields`.

I have seen different solutions like just giving `String` `'entry_page_objects[]'` to `fields_for` but I want to be consistent with rails naming convention and I know I can use `form_tag` instead of `form_for` but I want to make `fields_for` work as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some information for all that have not understood properly how `nested_attributes` works, like me.

What I have reported as issue is actually how it is supposed to work. When we have, let say, this model:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base # it has name attribute
  has_many :larodis
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :larodi
end

class Larodi < ActiveRecord::Base # it has name attribute
  belongs_to :foo
end
```

This definition gives me the possibility to create `Foo` with many `Larodi`'s just by giving a hash of parameters. For example:

```
x = Foo.create(name: 'Josh', larodi_attributes: [ {name: 'Wayne'} ]
x.larodis.map(&:name) # ['Wayne']
```

Now comes the part where `#field_for` understands if we have nested attribute to work with. We check this by looking for `name_attributes=` method. If it is defined `#fields_for` generates form of the type `<input ... name=object[name][INDEX][method]>...` where index is just an integer.

Keep in mind that when implementing custom `name_attibutes(attributes)` you must check attributes type - it can be `Array` like the example, it can be `Hash` of this type:

```
{ 1 => { ... } , 2 => { ... } }
```

Just like a hash representing array, where the key is index and value is the value for this index.

The answear looks like this:

`_form.html.haml`

```
....
= crawler_form.fields_for :entry_pages do |entry_page_field|
  %li
    =entry_page_field.text_field :url, size: 80
...
```

`company_crawler.rb`

```
class CompanyCrawler < ActiveRecord::Base
  ....
  serialize :entry_pages, Array

  def entry_pages_attributes=(attributes)
    self.entry_pages = attributes_collection(attributes).map do |attribute|
      EntryPage.new(attribute[:url])
    end
  end

  def entry_pages=(entry_pages)
    entry_pages = entry_pages.map do |entry_page|
      cast_entry_page_to_entry_page_object(entry_page)
    end

    write_attribute(:entry_pages, entry_pages)
  end

  ...

  private

  def attributes_collection(attributes)
    case attributes
    when Array
      attributes
    when Hash
      attributes.values
    end
  end

  def cast_entry_page_to_entry_page_object(entry_page)
    case entry_page
    when String
      EntryPage.new(entry_page)
    when EntryPage
      entry_page
    end
  end
end
```

For clarity I have removed `entry_page_objects` and use only `entry_pages`.